# Exchanging X and Y axes

Tags: plotting

I was wondering if I could have help with the rotation of the axis of my plot.

```
S[z] = 
 ListPlot[
   {{0.3451, 0}, 
    {3.61504, 14.5525503047423}, {6.43385, 28.1359640888397}, 
    {8.20271, 35.8693997314435}, {10.36884, 40.0596469567131}, 
    {12.70524, 40.7344299897916}, {14.6349, 49.3205653991629}, 
    {16.64968, 47.236883162213}, {18.57934, 53.6723782396654}, 
    {20.42387, 60.1963170848129}, {23.15755, 61.0961774098441}, 
    {25.49395, 67.8907159035738}, {27.74521, 66.7281232290898}, 
    {29.35326, 74.270969135446}, {30.72483, 69.3890375468614}, 
    {32.89096, 84.4267811980949}, {34.0166, 84.5491651221964}}, 
   Joined -> True]

data = 
  {{0.3451, 0}, 
   {3.61504, 14.5525503047423}, {6.43385, 28.1359640888397}, 
   {8.20271, 35.8693997314435}, {10.36884, 40.0596469567131}, 
   {12.70524, 40.7344299897916}, {14.6349, 49.3205653991629}, 
   {16.64968, 47.236883162213}, {18.57934, 53.6723782396654}, 
   {20.42387, 60.1963170848129}, {23.15755, 61.0961774098441}, 
   {25.49395, 67.8907159035738}, {27.74521, 66.7281232290898}, 
   {29.35326, 74.270969135446}, {30.72483, 69.3890375468614}, 
   {32.89096, 84.4267811980949}, {34.0166, 84.5491651221964}};

S = Interpolation[data];

Plot2525 = Plotmeasured = 
  Plot[S[z], {z, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}]
Labeled[
  Rotate[Show[Plot2525, PlotRange -> All ], 270 Degree], 
  {"Depth m", " Unit shaft friction (KPa)"}, 
  {Left, Top}, 
  RotateLabel -> True]
```

It needs to be rotated 90 degree.

Answer (score 2):

Flip horizontal & vertical axes:

```
ListLinePlot[Reverse /@ data]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Roman.... would you mind if answered me about rotate just the axis number

Comment: I don't mean flip or rotate the figure, just rotate the axis number... All of the respect

Comment: What is the "axis number"? Do you mean the tick labels?

Comment: yes dear tick labels

Comment: `Reverse[data, 2]` works too.